# Nodejs : Udp server issues

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, server, ip-address

I'm new to Node.js and Networking too. So started with the official docs.

I am working on a small chat application. The following is the code for it. This is the code for a single message client.  I used this program for broadcasting (code below). It is not complete, but just would serve as a reference. I have managed to broadcast a message and it was successfully received on different machine.

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

HOST = 'my local ip address as shown in ifconfig'

var message = new Buffer ('Server 1 sending my datagram');
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 4000, '224.0.0.14');

//// Bind to port 4000
port = 4000;
server.bind(port, function(){
server.addMembership('224.0.0.15',HOST);
});
```

During testing locally in different terminal tabs, I didn't include the 'HOST' variable in the addMembership call. And still it was working. But while I switched between different machines, I has to include it. Why?

Another thing I want to know is that if I want to make this application scalable, Is there a way to make the allocation of the ipaddress  (used as 224.0.0.14) in this example, randomly, so that it doesn't clashes with someone else using the same chat application? Or I''ll have to use different ports? The problem is I can't use the IPaddress of the LAN network. Nodejs gives me Error/Event Invalid Value.

Comment: The multicast addresses 224.0.0.14 and 224.0.0.15 are already spoken for: http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml  In general, stay away from anything in the 224.0.0.0/24 and 224.0.1.0/24 ranges.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But what will be the procedure to allocate Ip's automatically so as to give every device a unique one? @RonMaupin

Comment: Why'd one not use unassigned values in 224.0.0.X (say 224.0.0.3)? or (224.0.0.116-250)? In fact wouldn't that be recommended?

Comment: Though the above application was Broadcasting, I want to use it for peer to peer messaging, of which I think, will need to have different Ip addresses for every peer on the LAN. Also I want to know is there a procedure except than to assign different IP address to each machine, to make this application in Nodejs? @gabhijit

Comment: @gabhijit, the 224.0.0.0/24 multicast addresses are restricted to the link on which they are sent. A range such as 239.0.0.0/24 is designed for use in an organization. I'm not convinced multicast is the way to go on this since it offers no privacy.

Comment: @RonMaupin my understanding was that he intended to develop something  running on the link. In that case one could technically use `any`, but just so that it is portable, it's better if one uses `unassigned`. So I agree with you on that.

Comment: @PranavSharma - Use of multicast for peer to peer messaging is bad. You should use unicast addresses with some authentication. I think scope of that is much beyond the question.

Comment: @gabhijit I want to learn what would be the procedure to make a simple private chat application for multiple users on the same Local area Network. If it requires different Ip addresses assigned to different peers, Is there an algorithm to assign those Ip addresses? I dont want users to explicitly determine their own Ip addresses.

Comment: IP addresses are either manually configured for a PC, or they are assigned by DHCP. An application should not be involved in IP address assignment. Applications should worry about ports since ports are end-to-end addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin I will have to assign different ports to different machines to make this application work? If so, how would I be able to give different ports to different machines only through my application. How to check that they are not same for the two peers?

Comment: The difference is the IP address:port combination. You can use the same port (an unused one) for the application on each host, but the the IP address will be different for each host. The IP address will be the one already assigned to the host. I'm not sure you understand enough  about networking to be able to pull this off.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, I think I need to learn more about networks.